# discord.py how to check text channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make sure they can only save a **text channel** to a json file. I looked everywhere but found no solution to this problem. Can anyone help solve the problem?

```
@commands.command()
    async def goodbye(self, ctx, channel=None):
        try:
            channel = int(channel)
        except Exception as e:
            return await ctx.send('Please enter a channel id.')

        if len(str(channel)) != 18:
            await ctx.send('Invalid id.')

        elif self.client.get_channel(id=int(channel)):
            with open('./data/goodbye.json', 'r') as f:
                welcome = json.load(f)

            welcome[str(ctx.guild.id)] = f"{channel}"


            with open('./data/goodbye.json', 'w') as f:
                json.dump(welcome, f, indent=4)

            await ctx.send(f'Goodbye channel set: {channel}')

        else:
            await ctx.send('Channel not found!')
```

I found such a solution but i don't really know how to implement it:
`discord.TextChannel`

Comment: Maybe try to use `channel: discord.TextChannel` instead of just `channel=None`? Then you can get a text channel object immediately. If it's not a text channel, it would raise an error which can be handled.

Comment: Okay I get it, but if the solution would be best for me.

Comment: But then I have to forget this solution: 'channel = in (channel)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this answer your question?

```py
if isinstance(channel, discord.TextChannel):
    print("text channel")
```

or:

```py
if type(ctx.channel) == discord.TextChannel:
    print("text channel")
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of such a solution, but it doesn't want to work

Comment: I tried it with my bot and it works, that's weird.

Comment: The problem with the second option is that whatever value I enter, I always get this value: ```print ("text channel")```

Comment: The first option is like I didn't write into the script. It always goes to the next if.

Comment: I found the problem! For the type question in both cases (voice, text channel) I get the following value: 'discord.channel.Text Channel'

Comment: Cool, then just change the answer to the new type.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

```
    @commands.command()
    async def test(self, ctx, channel=None):

        channel2 = self.client.get_channel(id=int(channel))

        if type(channel2) != discord.channel.TextChannel:
            await ctx.send('Please do not enter an audio channel')

        else:
            await ctx.send('Perfect.')
```